# Eventlistener and closure in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

Though **removeEvent** is added, **console log in **customFunction**** prints multiple times with every render. I understand this has to do something with closure but not able to identify the solution. Any help is appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function addOnEvent(event_name, callback){
    document.addEventListener(event_name, (e)=>callback(e.detail));
}
function removeEvent(event_name, callback){
    document.removeEventListener(event_name, callback);
}
function App() {
  const [some_state, set_some_state] = useState([]);
    const customFunction = (e) => {
        //some action here setting some_state
        console.log("Console prints multiple times")
    };
  useEffect(() => {
    addOnEvent('custom_event', customFunction)
    return () => {
      removeEvent('custom_event', customFunction)
    };
  }, [some_state]);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you doing events like this in react? Does `custom_event` come from some third party, non-react lib that you have no control over? Just wondering because addEventListener is not a common thing to see in React.

Comment: why not move in customFunction in useEffect?

Answer (score 1):

You are not cleaning the event listener correctly. This is because you wrap the given callback with a new arrow function. So, `removeEventListener` will not find an event listener to remove.

You can fix this by removing the arrow function and extracting the `e.detail` in your `customFunction` instead.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function addOnEvent(event_name, callback){
    document.addEventListener(event_name, callback);
}
function removeEvent(event_name, callback){
    document.removeEventListener(event_name, callback);
}
function App() {
  const [some_state, set_some_state] = useState([]);
    const customFunction = (e) => {
        //some action here setting some_state
        console.log("Console prints multiple times")
    };
  useEffect(() => {
    addOnEvent('custom_event', customFunction)
    return () => {
      removeEvent('custom_event', customFunction)
    };
  }, [some_state]);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you really only want the `e.detail` in your callback, you can also update the `addOnEvent` function to return an unlisten function like so:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function addOnEvent(event_name, callback) {
  const listener = e => callback(e.detail);
  document.addEventListener(event_name, listener);
  return () => document.removeEventListener(event_name, listener);
}

function App() {
  const [some_state, set_some_state] = useState([]);
  const customFunction = (e) => {
    //some action here setting some_state
    console.log('Console prints multiple times');
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = addOnEvent('custom_event', customFunction);
    return () => unlisten();
  }, [some_state]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```